# Accessing values from Firebase in the component in Angular

Tags: angular, firebase, components

I have documents of users with first name and last name separated. I need access to them in the component and then merge them so I can save the whole name in another collection. So far I have only found broken or deprecated code from obsolete versions.
https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/firestore/documents.md
And with this code I don't get access in the component. 
How do I store the values in variables in the component so I can use them?

```
export interface user {
 first_name: string;
 last_name: string;
}
export class UserComponent {

 userCollection: AngularFirestoreCollection<user>;
 firstname: string;
 lastname: string;

 constructor(private afs: AngularFirestore) {
    this.userCollection.doc(this.user).ref.get().then(function(doc) {
    console.log(doc.data());
    *MISSING CODE*
    console.log(this.firstname, this.lastname);
  }
 }
```

Which .get or .ref or payload or doc.data() or .pipe do I have to use now to save the data from firebase in those 2 variables "firstname" and "lastname" so I can work with them in the component? I get the whole object in the console, but not each variable separated. It took me 4 days to find out that ".get()" on FirestoreCollections only works when I put a ".ref" in front of it, if anyone could help me to find this information faster, that would be very appreciated.

Comment: Please show the result of console.log(doc.data())

Comment: Then I get the object:
     Document data: 
{first_name: "John", last_name: "Doe", …}
first_name: "John"
last_name: "Doe"
__proto__: Object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since tou are getting the data, you could just assign it as follows,

```
 constructor(private afs: AngularFirestore) {
    this.userCollection.doc(this.user).ref.get().then(function(doc) {
    this.firstname = doc.data().first_name;
    this.lastname = doc.data().last_name;    
    console.log(this.firstname, this.lastname);
}
```

Comment: "Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot set property 'firstname' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot set property 'firstname' of undefined" But it is right below the userCollection.